# Undefined index: stream

Tags: php, json, api, mysqli

Estou estudando php e não consigo entender o motivo desse erro.
Ele executa o código como deve até certa parte. Basicamente eu estou tentando usar um banco de dados onde usuários vão inserir os nicks do twitch (tudo funcionando ok até aqui) e a partir desse banco de dados esse script vai verificar se eles estão online (no caso o script abaixo), se estiverem vão exibir um preview junto com o titulo. Porém exibe o erro e não carrega as outras streams no banco, apenas a primeira.

> Notice: Undefined index: stream in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sc2streams\online.php on line 22

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$resultado = mysqli_query($conecta, "select * from streams");
$name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
foreach ($name as $name) {
$streamsApi = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/';
$clientId = 'MinhaClientID';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Client-ID: ' . $clientId
),
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_URL => $streamsApi . $name
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);
if ($json['stream'] != ""){
echo "<div class='stream-div'><div class='container'>";
echo "<a href='" .$json['stream']['channel']['url']."'>"."<img src='".$json['stream']['preview']['medium']."' height='180' width='300'/></a><br>";
echo "<p>".$json['stream']['channel']['status']." - Jogando - ".$json['stream']['game']."</p><br>";
echo "</div></div>";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um dos avisos mais comuns pra quem está começando, basicamente ele serve pra te avisar que em algum lugar do seu código você está tentando acessar um índice de um vetor que não foi definido.

Quando você acessa um índice de um vetor e não pode garantir que ele existe, opte por utilizar a função `isset`, que retorna `true` se o parâmetro passado foi previamente definido e `false` caso contrário.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim no seu caso

```
if (isset($json['stream']) && $json['stream'] != "") {
    //seu comando
}
```

Lembrando que como você utilizou o operador &&, se a primeira condição for falsa a segunda nem é testada, o que evita o notice